# Which function to use for submiting a standard form

Tags: php, forms

I'm rahter confused about validating form inputs.
For example a simple form with inputs for `name`, `email`, `web address`, `password` and `textarea`

As I understand for text inputs I need to use:

```
trim()
tripslashes()
htmlspecialchars()
FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING
```

for email and web address

```
preg_match()
FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL
FILTER_SANITIZE_URL
FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL
FILTER_VALIDATE_URL
```

for password

```
hash()
```

I suppose there is a simpler way. Please suggestions and if possible an example of properly validated form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend understanding what each of those *do* before using them blindly as a "safety measure" because you can do more harm than good.

`trim` is to remove whitespaces in the left or in the right.

`stripslashes` un-quotes a quoted string.

`htmlspecialchars` translate special characters that have significance in HTML into HTML entities and you should use it when *outputting* HTML.

The filter flags (FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL, etc.) you'd use them with the [`filter_var`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.filter-var.php) function as in:

```
if (filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    // Email is valid
}
```

And for the password, you can use the [`hash`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.hash.php) function specifiying the hashing algorithm (md5, sha512, etc.). You may also want to look up on password salts to provide further security.